Flask app on GAE: CSRF token issues and session problems after first client
I'm having a weird issue with my Flask app deployed on Google App Engine (GAE). Here's what's happening:
The first client that connects after deployment works fine. The webapp functions as expected, with proper CSRF protection and session handling.
However, from the second client onwards, things go haywire:
The hidden CSRF token value remains the same for all subsequent clients.
Session cookies aren't being signed.
I'm getting errors about missing CSRF tokens.
I tried to unable csfr protection with no results since the problem is in sessions management. I tried different GAE configuration (basic and automatic scaling)

Can you check if the value of the SECRET_KEY is present and correct across all instances (in case there's more than one)?

Have a look at this link
